# Rolling Counter

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I need to use an existing table like this to facilitate rolling counters: -

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IdentityCounter](
    [CounterName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [StartId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [EndId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [CurrentId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [ModifiedTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

For example say I have the following: -

```
 CounterName  "ReceiptNumber"
 StartId  1
 EndId  99999 
 etc. etc.
```

For a particular CounterName I want to be able to call a stored procedure or function to: -

- To get me the next value and save that back to CurrentId and send the CurrentId back as the result
- If the next value equals EndId + 1 then I need to make the next value equal to StartId and save that back to CurrentId. Also send the CurrentId back as the result.
- There will be multiple applications calling this so need to ensure things remain consistent.

The counter is not a key it's just something that needs to be passed to a 3rd party service.

What's the best approach?

Thanks! ITG

Comment: Don't know about your application but seeing such a table raises some red alter flag in my head. Why aren't your counters associated to the corresponding entity tables? Why isn't your ReceiptNumber part of the Receipts table? I can't find any good reason for having such a counters table. But your mileage may vary, of course.

Comment: The ReceiptNumber is passed to a 3rd party service, we have a max of five digits to play with and it needs to roll. It's not a key of any sort. Sorry should have made that clearer in the initial question:(

Comment: If you are allowed to modify it, you should add declarative constraints to this table. I assume that the `CounterName` column is unique, and probably the primary key, so it should be declared as such. You should add a check constraint to `CurrentId` so that it can never be smaller than `StartId` or greater than `EndId`.

Comment: If your ID values are never greater than 99999, then `BIGINT` is an innappropriate data type. `INT` will store all these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I declare data that looks like the data in your question. It would be better if you declared this in your question so that we are all working with the same data. The data has one difference: the EndID is 5 instead of 99999 for demonstration purposes.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.IdentityCounter(
  CounterName,
  StartID,
  EndID,
  CurrentID
)
VALUES (
  N'ReceiptNumber',
  1,
  5,
  1
);
```

This procedure does what you ask for:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.IncrementCounter (
  @CounterName NVARCHAR(255)
)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE dbo.IdentityCounter
  SET CurrentID = CASE WHEN CurrentID = EndID THEN StartID ELSE CurrentID + 1 END
  OUTPUT DELETED.CurrentID
  WHERE CounterName = @CounterName;
END;
```

It returns a 'scalar' result set (one column, one row), which represents the value of `CurrentID` for the given CounterName before the counter is incremented.

Example of repeated execution:

```
EXEC dbo.IncrementCounter
  @CounterName = 'ReceiptNumber';
EXEC dbo.IncrementCounter
  @CounterName = 'ReceiptNumber';
EXEC dbo.IncrementCounter
  @CounterName = 'ReceiptNumber';
EXEC dbo.IncrementCounter
  @CounterName = 'ReceiptNumber';
EXEC dbo.IncrementCounter
  @CounterName = 'ReceiptNumber';
EXEC dbo.IncrementCounter
  @CounterName = 'ReceiptNumber';
EXEC dbo.IncrementCounter
  @CounterName = 'ReceiptNumber';
EXEC dbo.IncrementCounter
  @CounterName = 'ReceiptNumber';
EXEC dbo.IncrementCounter
  @CounterName = 'ReceiptNumber';
EXEC dbo.IncrementCounter
  @CounterName = 'ReceiptNumber';
```

Should output ten result sets similar to this sequence: `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`.

Comment: Re. data, yes, more practise required!! Thanks for taking the time out to answer much appreciated:)